# how to center text in fpdf?

Tags: programming-languages, web, fpdf

How can I have this generated text appear centered in the page.

Generated = $_POST method ... so I dont know how long will the text in input be... so I need to have a pre-determined center parameter somehow...

any ideas/??

Answer (score 0):

Do you want text to be centered horizontally or vertically?

In the first case, you could create a Cell or MultiCell  (for text that splits across many lines (http://www.id.uzh.ch/cl/zinfo/fpdf/doc/cell.htm http://www.id.uzh.ch/cl/zinfo/fpdf/doc/multicell.htm ) with no borders/background with zero width (so that it reaches the right margin of the page) and centre alignment.

I don't know if there is any easier way, avoiding the cells.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. cannot test it now, I guess MultiCell(0,$height,"text",0,'C') will do.